# Mongoose RESTful api object.id ref

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i try to build RESTful api for todos application.

Todos Scheme:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TodosScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todos', TodosScheme);
```

Task Scheme:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TaskScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    todosID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Todos'
    },
    content: String,
    isDone: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskScheme);
```

so if user create task it will be reference for some Todos item.

i start to write route for create todos list

```
app.post('/api/todos/create', (req, res) => {
    newTodos = new Todos({});
    newTodos.save((err, todos) => {
        if (err) res.status(400).json(err);
        res.json(todos);
    });
});
```

and now i try to write route to create task

```
app.post('/api/todos/create/task', (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(body);
    let newTask = new Task({
        todosID: body.todosID, //here i not sure!
        content: body.content || 'no content',
        isDone: body.isDone || false
    });

    newTask.save((err, task) => {
        if (err) res.status(400).json(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
});
```

so my questions is:
1) to create task i need to pass three params:

content: client will pass from request

isDone: client will pass from request

todosID: X ? client? it's the best way?

2) if client need to pass todosID, this is must be required on Task scheme?
because if user create task now without todosID he will create task without reference.

3) have a better way to write scheme todos app? 
thank for all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/api/todos/create` returns created `todos` object. It should contain `_id` property. To create task, you should send `todos._id` with `content` in request body.

Comment: ok so client must send todos._id, so it's must to be required on create task? and it good way to work?

Comment: Yes, client must send `todos._id`, and it's a correct way. It's not private info, for example this stackoverflow question has id, and you sent it to the server, when added your comment.